# ORO API non-resource structure

Tags: orocrm, orocommerce

I'm trying to make an API method for custom data structures that could work with relations to other API resources, but have issues with `normalize_input` action group processors.
For example, I need to process a list of `orderlineitems` elements and give a custom response. To approach this task, I created the model class of required structure.

```
class ListModel
{
   /** @var Collection|OrderLineItem[] */
   protected $lineItems;
   ...
}
```

And registered it in the `api_frontend.yml`:

```
api:
  entities:
    Ardex\Bundle\OrderBundle\Api\Model\CartProducts:
      disable_meta_properties: true
      fields:
        lineItems:
          target_class: Oro\Bundle\ProductBundle\Entity\Product
          target_type: to-many
        actions:
          get: false
          get_list: false
          update: false
          delete: false
          delete_list: false
          create: true
```

With help of Xdebug, I found that all request data should send in the `meta` parameter, and in this case `included` request body part is ignored.

Answer (score 0):

From the above information, the API framework doesn't know how to work with the CartProducts model, and what to do with the lineItems list. Because CartProducts is not an entity, and the resource even doesn't have an ID.

To make it work, you should map the data explicitly in a custom API processor for the `create` action.
See:

- [Creating an API processor](https://doc.oroinc.com/backend/api/processors/)
- [Create action implementation details](https://doc.oroinc.com/backend/api/actions/#create-action).

But I'm still not sure, it's a good idea to use the fully-featured API framework for the task. If you are not going to use any other actions than creating and the API resource is totally custom, maybe it is better to [create a custom API controller](https://doc.oroinc.com/backend/api/how-to/#add-a-custom-controller) and manage the complexity there explicitly.

From what we have in core as examples, you can check the `productcollection` resource, but it is read-only. There are no examples where the model refers to an entity, and the API framework couldn't know how to work with it.